# Little o notation with sum

Tags: limits

I was taught that $a_n\sim b_n => a_n=b_n +o(b_n)$
And that if $a_n\sim a'_n$ and $b_n\sim b'_n$ this does NOT imply $a_n + b_n\sim a'_n + b'_n$
Then, I saw this: 
$lim_{(n->\infty)}\frac{...}{ln(1+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3})+\frac1{n^5}} $=
$lim_{(n->\infty)}\frac{...}{(\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}+o(\frac1{n^2}))+\frac1{n^5}} $
I get that $ln(1+\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3})\sim\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}$, but there's another term in the denominator. Can someone explain me how does this work?

Comment: Please note that $\ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3})\sim\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}\sim\frac{1}{n^2}\sim\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac1{n^{42}}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
$$\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)+\frac{1}{n^5}=\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$